# Programmatically created Image folder not shown in the Public folder

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image

I'm new to Android Development. I have developed a program that capture images via camera and stored in mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MYFOLDER. And also there is another button foe browse images. image save perfectly. But when I browse the taken images by clicking Browse button it only shows these folders: Pictures,Bluetooth,images. When I navigate to Pictures folder MYFOLDER does not exist.

here is my Browse button

```
 Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBrowseimage);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some times it happens that gallary not show the newly created directory. I don't know why but may be due to not scanned newly created/modified directory.

**Solution**

Restart your device.

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake, glad to help... please if you can accept the answer.. pleasure is mine.. :)

Comment: Can we refresh it parametrically?

Comment: You can't.. There is only solution like you create a custom grid view which loads gallery images.. Then only you can do that.. I have same problem and do like that..Then also.. you need to go to root directory and scan files instead of MediaContent...Sad but true.. :(

Answer (score 4):

Instead of restarting fire this broadcast which will help re-indexing of the newly created folder or file and the resulting folder will be visible in the gallery:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, mediaMountUri));
```