# Which folders appear in Gallery of an Android device?

Tags: android

Im building an application and I've made a folder inside the home directory of the device (where folder like Music, Movies, Download are) in which I've placed some photos. The problem is that these photos don't appear in the "Gallery" of the device.

Where should I place the photos to be displayed in the Gallery? Which folders are scanned to be appeared in the Gallery?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21473238/3981656

Comment: "The problem is that these photos don't appear in the "Gallery" of the device" -- they will eventually, though that may be a day or so. Use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to arrange for your images to be indexed more quickly.

Comment: I've restarted the device many times but it didn't work. I've also used the following code: 

sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString())));

both as it is and also pointing to a particular file

Comment: Also this one : MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                mContext,
                new String[]{Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()},
                null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.v("scan",
                                "file " + path + " was scanned seccessfully: " + uri);
                    }
                });